# Reverse linear gradient with css Property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div filled with linear gradient colour. On a click of button i want to reverse the linear gradient colour. I achieved it again by changing linear gradient value. Instead of changing the linear gradient value i want to know is there is any specific `CSS` property to reverse the linear gradient. Hope you understood my ask

```js
var color  =  document.getElementById('color');
var btn = document.getElementById('reverse');
reverse.onclick = reverseColor;
function reverseColor(){
 color.style.background = "linear-gradient(to right, rgb(237,195 ,194) 0% ,rgb(237,195 ,194) 20%, rgb(226,167 ,165) 20% ,rgb(226,167 ,165) 40%, rgb(215,138 ,136) 40% ,rgb(215,138 ,136) 60%, rgb(203,110 ,106) 60% ,rgb(203,110 ,106) 80%, rgb(192,81 ,77) 80% ,rgb(192,81 ,77) 100%)";
}
```

```css
.linear{
  width:200px;
  height:30px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(192,81 ,77) 0% ,rgb(192,81 ,77) 20%, rgb(203,110 ,106) 20% ,rgb(203,110 ,106) 40%, rgb(215,138 ,136) 40% ,rgb(215,138 ,136) 60%, rgb(226,167 ,165) 60% ,rgb(226,167 ,165) 80%, rgb(237,195 ,194) 80% ,rgb(237,195 ,194) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="color" class="linear">

</div>
<button id="reverse" style="margin-top:50px">
Reverse Gradient
</button>
```

Comment: [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hcs181f2/)

Hopefully, this will help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just toggle `to right` and `to left` in linear gradient.

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/shubham_agr10/u4p1fd2o/)**

Here is the code:

```js
var color = document.getElementById('color');
var btn = document.getElementById('reverse');
myVar = "left";

function colorfn() {
  color.style.background = "linear-gradient(to " + myVar + ", rgb(237,195 ,194) 0% ,rgb(237,195 ,194) 20%, rgb(226,167 ,165) 20% ,rgb(226,167 ,165) 40%, rgb(215,138 ,136) 40% ,rgb(215,138 ,136) 60%, rgb(203,110 ,106) 60% ,rgb(203,110 ,106) 80%, rgb(192,81 ,77) 80% ,rgb(192,81 ,77) 100%)";
}
btn.onclick = function() {
  myVar = myVar == "left" ? "right" : "left";
  colorfn();
}

colorfn();
```

```css
.linear {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="color" class="linear">

</div>

<button id="reverse" style="margin-top:50px">
  Reverse Gradient
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, there isn't exactly a specific CSS property to do that besides using the `to right` keywords as you did. But there is a *hackish* way to do it in case you really need to.

This is how I would do it:

```
var color = document.getElementById('color');
var btn = document.getElementById('reverse');
reverse.onclick = reverseColor;

var transformDeg = 0;

function reverseColor() {

  if (transformDeg == 0) {
    transformDeg = 180;
    color.style.transform = "rotateY(" + transformDeg + "deg)";
  } else {
    transformDeg = 0;
    color.style.transform = "rotateY(" + transformDeg + "deg)";
  }
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/xqmdw501/)

Also note that doing it this way will also reverse all contents. So this might be or not be appropriate depending on what you want to achieve :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class.

```js
var color = document.getElementById('color');
var btn = document.getElementById('reverse');
reverse.onclick = reverseColor;

function reverseColor() {

  color.classList.toggle('reverse');
 
}
```

```css
.linear {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(192, 81, 77) 0%, rgb(192, 81, 77) 20%, rgb(203, 110, 106) 20%, rgb(203, 110, 106) 40%, rgb(215, 138, 136) 40%, rgb(215, 138, 136) 60%, rgb(226, 167, 165) 60%, rgb(226, 167, 165) 80%, rgb(237, 195, 194) 80%, rgb(237, 195, 194) 100%);
}

.reverse {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(237, 195, 194) 0%, rgb(237, 195, 194) 20%, rgb(226, 167, 165) 20%, rgb(226, 167, 165) 40%, rgb(215, 138, 136) 40%, rgb(215, 138, 136) 60%, rgb(203, 110, 106) 60%, rgb(203, 110, 106) 80%, rgb(192, 81, 77) 80%, rgb(192, 81, 77) 100%)
}
```

```html
<div id="color" class="linear">

</div>
<button id="reverse" style="margin-top:50px">
Reverse Gradient
</button>
```

Comment: Dude this will not work good. If have many DIV linear background to be reverse. I cant have separate class for each div to reverse

Comment: just put the button inside a main div and use parent via js